# how can i avoide zombie proccess

Tags: linux, sockets

I have this code:

**server**

```
    while(1){ //loop the child

         bzero(buffer, 256);
         n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 255,0);
        printf("read %d ",n);
        printf("pid %d\n",getpid());
         if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");{
             printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);

        }
        if (strcmp(buffer,"quit") == 0){
            printf("Disconnect from %s:%d\n",str,portno);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }else{  
             n = send(newsockfd, "message received\n", 19,0);
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
             bzero(buffer, 256);

            }
     }
   }else{ //parent 
    recv(newsockfd,gepid,10,0); //get the child pid
    endID = waitpid(gepid,&status,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED); //get the exit code gepid want to be the child pid 
    if (endID==-1){
         error("waitpid");
    }else if (endID==0){
        printf("Child still running!");
     }else if(endID==childpid){
        check_child_exit(status);
    }       
  } 
}   
    close(newsockfd);

       return 0;
}
```

**client**

```
    while(1){ //while after connect 
    printf(inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));
printf(" :>");
    bzero(buffer, 256);


printf("pid: %d",&getpid);
    //fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

scanf("%s",&buffer[0]); 
 if ( send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer),0)< 0)
         error("ERROR writing to socket");

if(strcmp(buffer,"quit") == 0){
    close(sockfd);
    printf("Client: %s Disconnect \n",inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));
    gepid[0]=getpid();  //there is the error i want to get the pid of child 
    send(sockfd,gepid,10,0); //and send to server
    exit(1);
    }   



if (recv(sockfd, buffer, 255,0)< 0){
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
}else{
printf("%s\n %d", buffer,n);
 }  
}  

  return 0;
}
```

I have a server that can serve multy client and response to each one when the client write quit or stop with a signal[CTR-C] i want the server get that and avoid zombie proccess so to avoid zombie proccess i thought
 to send from client to server the getpid so the client get the pid of the kid proccess when the proccess finish with quit or stop by signal parent get the exit with waitpaid
so the programm not have zombie proccess i dont know if this logic is good to stop the zombie proccess but i try to send pid from client to server and i get segmentation fault

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code, but to focus on your question:

Don't try sending the pid to the server. It's unnecessary, and wouldn't work if the child crashes before it can send it anyway.

The usual way is to catch the SIGCHLD signal, and do any necessary `waitpid` stuff from inside the signal handler. But if your *only* concern is avoiding zombies, then just install a default signal handler with `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);`, and don't use `waitpid` at all.

Comment: can you explain me how to use the SIGCHLD i am new in this coding?

Comment: Put `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);` in the server, somewhere before your main loop, that's it. And if you later really want to handle the signal yourself, you should be able to find many examples by just googling SIGCHLD.

Comment: yeah thnx i just put a handle method for signal

Answer (score 0):

[fork() returns 0 in the child and the child pid in the parent](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), so there is no need to send pid from child to parent. If you are forking multiple times, then you need to store each child pid for collection later.

You are not showing the type of gepid. Is it pid_t gepid[2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) or something? The [len parameter to recv()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) is in bytes, so it would be more appropriate to recv(sock, gepid, sizeof(gepid[0]), 0);

Also if you pass -1 to [waitpid()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), it waits for any child.